# how to run django cron job with which function

Tags: python, django, cron

I have an app that needs a cron job. specifically, for ranking part I need my file to run synchronously so the score changes in the background. Here is my code.
I have rank.py in my utils folder

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from math import log


epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)


def epoch_seconds(date):
    td = date - epoch
    return td.days * 86400 + td.seconds + (float(td.microseconds) / 1000000)


def score(ups, downs):
    return ups - downs


def hot(ups, downs, date):
    s = score(ups, downs)
    order = log(max(abs(s), 1), 10)
    sign = 1 if s > 0 else -1 if s < 0 else 0
    seconds = epoch_seconds(date) - 1134028003
    return round(sign * order + seconds / 45000, 7)
```

And I have the two functions under Post model, inside models.py

```
def get_vote_count(self):

        vote_count = self.vote_set.filter(is_up=True).count() - self.vote_set.filter(is_up=False).count()
        if vote_count >= 0:
            return "+ " + str(vote_count)
        else:
            return "- " + str(abs(vote_count))

    def get_score(self):
        """ 
        :return: The score calculated by hot ranking algorithm
        """
        upvote_count = self.vote_set.filter(is_up=True).count()
        devote_count = self.vote_set.filter(is_up=False).count()
        return hot(upvote_count, devote_count, self.pub_date.replace(tzinfo=None))
```

Problem is I'm not sure how to run cron job for this. I've seen http://arunrocks.com/building-a-hacker-news-clone-in-django-part-4/ and it looks like I need to create another file and another function to make the whole thing run. again and again./but what function?How do I use cron job for my code? I saw there are many applications that allow me to do this, but I'm just not sure which funcction I need to use and how I should use. my guess is I need to run get_score function in models.py but how....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may consider celery and rabbitmq

the idea is: in your app you create a file called tasks.py and there you put the code:

```
# tasks.py
from celery import task

@task
def your_task_for_async_job(data):
    # todo
```

just call the function and it does the job for you asyncly..

[Here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) is the documentation for Celery, you find there also how to set it up with django etc..

hope, this helps

Comment: yeah thanks I read about celery but  the question I'm having; I don't know what to put in todo part

Comment: @mikebraa you put the code that you want to run asynchronously

Comment: oh I see, so in my case it would it be like  get_score method right?

Comment: because I want the ranking to be run

Comment: @mikebraa you may want to upvote and accept this as answer ;)

Comment: by the way do you know how to let users to post image, do you mind taking a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836267/user-to-upload-pictures-in-django-set-everything-i-can-think-but-nothing-gets-p?noredirect=1#comment57413699_34836267?